# Problems using .replaceWith(); with youtube iframe

Tags: jquery

I made a jQuery slider that moves divs around to make the sliding effect.

Links are like this:

```
<ul id="navigation">
   <li class="element"><a href="#item1" class="panel , current" id="no"></a></li>
   <li class="element"><a href="#item2" class="panel" id="no"></a></li>
   <li class="element"><a href="#item3" class="panel" id="no"></a></li>
   <li class="element"><a href="#item4" class="panel" id="yes"></a></li>
   <li class="element"><a href="#item5" class="panel" id="no"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I have a YouTube iframe in the #item4 div and to stop the audio from playing when the user navigates I am using .remove();

eg.

```
$('ul#navigation li.element a#no').click(function () {
    $('#video').remove();
});
```

This works fine on its own. The video loads and is playable then if any of the #no links are clicked the divs slide and the video stops playing.

I am trying to add the video back in when the #yes link is clicked using:

```
$('ul#navigation li.element a#yes').click(function () {
        $('#video').replaceWith('<iframe id="video" title="Showreel" width="780" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XR3xr8PAuJY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    });
```

Which doesn't work and stops the .remove from working as well.
I assume it is because of all the " 's that are flying everywhere within the iframe.

How can I get around this problem?

I tried using .show and .hide plus .css("display" "none") but the audio keeps playing.
Is there are a better way than .remove and .replaceWith to do this?

Thanks people

*EDIT*

I just realised I could probably do away with the .remove and just use .replaceWith to insert the iframe when the #yes link is clicked but I still have the syntax problems.

Could the problem be because I am trying to replace #video with an html string containing the same id?

*EDIT 2*
I can't figure out the markdown for comments.

I just tried:

```
$('#videobox').append('<iframe id="video" title="Showreel" width="780" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XR3xr8PAuJY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

where #videobox is the div that the iframe was sitting in before it was removed.
This still breaks the .remove()

Answer (score 0):

You removed the `#video` element previously, so you can't do `$('#video').replaceWith(...)`.  `$('#video')` will not find anything to operate `.replaceWith()` on.

You would have to use `.append()` or one of the other jQuery DOM insertion functions to insert the newly created iframe into the right parent object.

You can control the iframe youtube video from javascript using Google's APIs.  Here's an example of that: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/D9Zjf/.

Comment: Wow you are fast!
I just read through my post and realised the same thing. If I just swap .replaceWith with .append will this work?

Comment: Youtube has a javascript API so you should be able to pause or change the video without totally destroying and recreating everything.  I am not familiar with the API myself, but perhaps some Googling for how to do it will find some sample code.